# Found conflicts between different versions of system.numerics.vectors that could not be resolved

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to create a .apk from my Xamarin.Forms project. When I right-click on the Android project and click on "Archive for Publishing" I get this error:

> Found conflicts between different versions of system.numerics.vectors
> that could not be resolved

I don't get this error when I build and deploy on my Android emulator, only when I click on "Archive for Publishing". The 3 projects for Android are:

`MyProject.Core` (.NET Standard 2.1)
`MyProject.lib` (.NET Standard 2.1)
`MyPorject.Android` (target Android 12.0)

I also have an iOS and UITests projects in my solution. Both `MyProject.Core` and `MyPorject.Android` reference `MyProject.lib`. They all have packages that have `System.Numerics.Vectors` version 4.5.0 in them. It's possible that 1 of them has a package that contains a different version of this library that I missed (I manually went through them all in the solution explorer).

Answer (score 0):

I added this in the Release section of build in the .csproj and it works now:

```
<ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
```

I had it in the Debug but not in the Release build configuration.